# Почему id всегда 1 Yii2

Tags: yii, авторизация

Использую все как по документации. Для получения информации о пользователе использую

```
$identity = $model->findOne(['email' => $_POST['User']['email']]);
```

И каким бы не был email, id пользователя всегда 1
Почему? Мне надо знать правильный, весь функционал на этом завязан

Описание класса User

```
<?php
namespace common\models\accounts;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use Yii;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

public $password_repeat;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'user';
}

public function rules(){
    return [];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password_hash' => 'Пароль',
        'password_repeat' => 'Повторите пароль',
        'sid' => 'Школа',
        'type' => 'Тип пользователя'
    ];
}

/**
 * Finds an identity by the given ID.
 *
 * @param string|integer $id the ID to be looked for
 * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given ID.
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}

/**
 * Finds an identity by the given token.
 *
 * @param string $token the token to be looked for
 * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given token.
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
}

/**
 * @return int|string current user ID
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return string current user auth key
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @param string $authKey
 * @return boolean if auth key is valid for current user
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->auth_key = \Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static public function getUserType()
{
    return [
        -1 => 'Не проверен',
        0 => 'admin',
        1 => 'Директор',
        2 => 'Завуч',
        3 => 'Методист',
        4 => 'Тренер',
        5 => 'Спортсмен',
        6 => 'Опекун'
    ];
}

static public function getUserTypeForPublic($exclude = false)
{
    $userTypes = self::getUserType();
    $newUserType = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
    {
        $newUserType[$i] = $userTypes[$i];
    }

    return $newUserType;
}
}
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecordinterface.html#findOne()-detail

Comment: не понял, что вы имели ввиду, но я написал так `$model->find()->where(['id' => 4])->one();` и мне все равно выводит, что id найденного пользователя - 1

Comment: в логах есть такой запрос к базе - `SELECT * FROM 'user' WHERE 'id'=4`, который должен вывести все верно, но не выводит

Comment: я имел в виду, что метод findOne статичный - это раз, возвращает $activeRecord - это два, по нему можно найти тома информации это 3. Откуда вы взяли `->findOne` метод, который ещё и возвращает $identity - я не знаю, и подозреваю что это какой-то самопал. Поэтому минус - за недостаточное освещение вопроса.

Comment: https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/security-authentication/ - вот тут описан процес, а именно там есть строчки "Для залогинивания пользователя вы можете использовать следующий код: `$identity = User::findOne(['username' => $username]); Yii::$app->user->login($identity);`

Comment: вот я и говорю - самопал `class User extends ActiveRecord` . Это что по вашему, встроено в yii ? Добавьте описание самопала в вопрос, или лучше обойдитесь без него в вопросе - воспроизведите баг встроенными в yii компонентами. А лучше делайте по английским мануалам - google translate гораздо продуктивнее украинских статей.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр ну вообще-то да... в базовом темплейте фремворка есть модель User которая наследуется от ActiveRecord  и имплементирует IdentityInterface, если что на секундочку..... лишь в самой последней версии в base template extends Object написано....а у advanced template так и в последненей именно activerecord

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, добавил в вопрос описание класса. я новичек в yii2 поэтому извините, если что то делаю не так. я читаю инструкции и но них делаю

Comment: и вот нашел такую же статью в официальной документации по yii2 - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр если вы правда не понимаете, что статику можно вызывать на экземплярах, а identity - это название перемнной, то вопросы тут не к автору.

Comment: @Etki можно. Ты считаешь - это нормально? Я тут не просто даю ответы как робот - пытаюсь сделать мир чуток лучше.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр то, что там выше в комментариях, больше похоже на прессинг на ровном месте.

Answer (score 0):

Понятно - что нужно детально отлаживать, такого быть не должно разумеется.
Только вызывайте пожалуйста метод для получения юзера по email так:

```
$identity = User::findIdentity(['email' => $_POST['User']['email']]);
/*Правда метод findIdentity - расчитывает на тип аргумента string|integer - указано в его phpdoc. 
А User::findOne - может принимать и массив - тогда лучше использовать findOne.
 */
```

`$identity` - по мне так не слишком очевидное название модели пользователя, по названию кажется что это числовой id, но возможно в yii так принято. Возможно ошибка как-раз в том, что вы каким-то кривым образом сконструировали `$model` до получения собственно модели, которая вас интересует ( `$identity` ). Попробуйте убрать создание `$model`

Если не поможет, нужно проверить:
1. Структуру таблицы `user` - в таблице пользователя должны быть колонки `email` (UK) , `id` (PK, AI)
2. `$_POST['User']['email']` - проверьте, не пустая ли переменная.
3. Проверьте, не переопределён ли в цепочке наследования (которая должна быть User -> ActiveRecord -> BaseActiveRecord -> Model -> Component -> Object ) метод __get - переопределение может искажать реальные данные. Обратите внимание на код исходного метода __get в `BaseActiveRecord` :

```
public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->_attributes[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $this->_attributes)) {
            return $this->_attributes[$name];
        } elseif ($this->hasAttribute($name)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            if (isset($this->_related[$name]) || array_key_exists($name, $this->_related)) {
                return $this->_related[$name];
            }
            $value = parent::__get($name);
            if ($value instanceof ActiveQueryInterface) {
                return $this->_related[$name] = $value->findFor($name, $this);
            } else {
                return $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

И попробуйте в нём встроить для отладки: `var_dump($this->_attributes, $this->_related); die();` - это прояснит ситуацию.